# How to handle big textual data to create WordCloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bigdata, word-cloud

I have a huge textual data that I need to create its word cloud. I am using a `Python` library named `word_cloud` in order to create the word cloud which is quite configurable. The problem is that my textual data is really huge, so a high-end computer is not able to complete the task even for long hours.

The data is firstly stored in `MongoDB`. Due to `Cursor` issues while reading the data into a `Python list`, I have exported the whole data to a plain text file - simply a `txt` file which is `304 MB`.

So the question that I am looking for the answer is how can I handle this huge textual data? The `word_cloud` library needs a `String` parameter that contains the whole data separated with `' '` in order to create the `Word Cloud`.

p.s. `Python` version: `3.7.1`

p.s. `word_cloud` is an open source `Word Cloud` generator for `Python` which is available on GitHub: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load all the file in memory.

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from collections import Counter

wc = WordCloud()

counts_all = Counter()

with open('path/to/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:  # Here you can also use the Cursor
        counts_line = wc.process_text(line)
        counts_all.update(counts_line)

wc.generate_from_frequencies(counts_all)
wc.to_file('/tmp/wc.png')
```